# Parsing XML data into a dynamic HTML Select Satement

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

What I would like to do is create 2 select statements and when the first has an option selected to use an "onChange" event to change the options of the second select statement.

Here is a good demo of what I am going for:  http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/working-examples/SCR19/dynselect.html

And the corresponding code:  http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR19.html

But instead of using an array to populate the options in the select statement, I would prefer to parse the data from an XML document.

XML Doc would be something like:

```
<inventory>
  <shoes>
    <item>
      <name>Chuck Taylor Converse</name>
      <size>11</size>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
    </item>
  </shoes>
</inventory>
```

What I have been thinking is to use XSL for-each statements and a Javascript function to change the options of the second select statement.

```
//  Shows the name of each type of product from the XML doc
<select id="type" onchange="showProducts(this);">
  <xsl:for-each select="inventory/*">
    <option><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></option>
  </xsl:for-each>    
</select>

<select id="product">
</select>
```

What I am stuck on is trying to figure out how I can accomplish this in Javascript.  Do I need to parse the XML into an array?  My other idea was to try and do a document.write with an XSL statement but I could't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either apply the XSLT server-side - this means that the JavaScript will receive already the HTML fragment that can be inserted directly in the page - using jQuery:

```
$('#product').load('mysever/url_returning_the_html');
```

or the server can provide the raw XML and you apply the XSLT using JavaScript - and how to do this depends on the browser, see http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp for an example.

My suggestion would be to do as much as possible the transformation server-side, and provide to the JavaAcript code either HTML - that can be used directly, or JSON - that is more compact and easy to parse in JavaScript.

Comment: I followed the linked you supplied and after downloading the corresponding xml and xsl files and creating a new html file I was unable to get it to function in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Works for me - IE9, Chrome, Safari.